# How to make div element ng-repeat show one div inside at a time automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to make contents of each div element one at a time with some delay. What is best solution or possible ways to do this transition. Here is current code :

HTML code:

```
   <div>
    <div class="content repeat-item" data-ng-repeat="item in ItemsList">
        <div>{{item.ItemColumn2}}</div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

CSS code:

```
.content.repeat-item.ng-enter,
.content.repeat-item.ng-leave {
-webkit-transition:0.5s linear all;
 transition:0.5s linear all;
 }

.content.repeat-item.ng-enter,
 .content.repeat-item.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity:0;
 }
 .content.repeat-item.ng-leave,
 .content.repeat-item.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity:1;
 }
```

Here Itemslist and menu_info data are coming from angularjs controller scope variables. I am unable to  loop ng-repeat as  with content one at a time.

Comment: Unclear what you asking. Probably because you mention issues with CSS while there is no CSS in your question, but also because I don't really understand by makeing a tile 'live'.

Comment: I edit my div. I am trying to load div's created by ng-repeat to loop and show one div at a time. is it possible ?

Comment: you should edit your question to be more specific on the css part or delete the css part.

Comment: I have removed css from div. I want to slide one div at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question is unclear..   u need to display only the first element of the ng-repeat ?
for only displaying first element you can use this

`<div>
    <div class="content repeat-item" data-ng-repeat="item in ItemsList"  ng-show="$first">
        <div>{{item.ItemColumn2}}</div>
    </div>
</div>`